# Ionic and Arduino communication via Bluetooth

Tags: javascript, cordova, bluetooth, arduino, ionic-framework

```js
// Ionic Starter LLc

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snLLcing when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
var LLc = {
 intialize: function() {
  this.bind();
 },
 bind: function(){
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.deviceready, true);
 },
 //the device is ready for use
 deviceready: function() {
  Auto.checked = LLc.Cycle;
  Note.checked = LLc.Notifications;
  
  // throttle changes
        var throttledCChange = _.throttle(LLc.CChange, 200);
        $('input').on('change', throttledCChange);
        
 },
 //handles the color changes done by the sliders
 CChange: function (evt) {
  var c = LLc.ColorChange();
  LLc.ArduinoPush(c);
 },
 //creates an array to hold all the slider values into, that will be fed to arduino
 ColorChange: function(){
  var color = [];
  color.push(red.value);
  color.push(green.value);
  color.push(blue.value);
  return color.join(',');
 },
 ArduinoPush: function (c){
  bluetoothSerial.write("c" + c + "\n");
 },
 //color cycle mode for arduino
 Cycle: function(){
  red.value = 0;
  green.value = 0;
  blue.value = 0;
  while(Auto.checked == true){
   while(red.value < 250){
   if(blue.value > 0 ){blue.value = blue.value - 25;}
   red.value = red.value + 25;
   var c = LLc.getColor();
   LLc.ArduinoPush(c)
   }
   while(green.value < 250){
   green.value = green.value + 25;
   red.value = red.value - 25;
   var c = LLc.getColor();
   LLc.ArduinoPush(c)
   }
   while(blue.value < 250){
   blue.value = blue.value + 25;
   green.value = green.value - 25;
   var c = LLc.getColor();.
   LLc.ArduinoPush(c)
   }
  }

 },
 Notifications: function(){
  
 },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/topcoat-mobile-dark.min.css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
 
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
 
 <!--ng-cordova Script -->
 <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="Starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
     <h1 class="topcoat-navigation-bar">
            <div class="topcoat-navigation-bar__item center full">
                <h1 class="topcoat-navigation-bar__title">LovellLight Companion</h1>
            </div>
        </h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
 <li class="item item-toggle">
  AutoMode
  <label class="toggle toggle-calm"> 
   <input type="checkbox" id="Auto">
   <div class="track">
    <div class="handle">
    </div> 
   </div> 
  </label>
 </li>
 <li class="item item-toggle">
  Notification Mode
  <label class="toggle toggle-assertive"> 
   <input type="checkbox" id="Note">
   <div class="track">
    <div class="handle">
    </div> 
   </div> 
  </label>
 </li>
  <div class="list">
   <div class="item range range-positive">
    <div class= "positive"> Blue </div>
    <input type="range" name="blue" id="blue" min="0" max="250" value="0"> 
    <i class="icon ion-plus-circled"></i>
   </div>
  
   <div class="item range range-assertive">
    <div class= "assertive"> Red </div>
    <input type="range" name="red" id="red" min="0" max="250" value="0"> 
    <i class="icon ion-plus-circled"></i>
   </div> 
  
   <div class="item range range-balanced">
    <div class= "balanced"> Green </div>
    <input type="range" name="green" id="green" min="0" max="250" value="0"> 
    <i class="icon ion-plus-circled"></i>
   </div>
  </div>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>  
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hello All! I'm new to Ionic app development and had a few question on how to get started, or moreso how to get my app and my Arduino trading information. I am trying to make a simple app to be able to change the color of a light on a adafruit ring light connected to the Arduino. Problem is, I have be unsuccessful in being able to get them to speak.

Because I want to make this app as simple as possible, I have followed the PhoneGap tutorial for light changes as far as actually changing color and sending data to the Arduino is concered, but have been unable to get any reliable feedback to the Arduino, or any feedback whatsoever. this is especially concerning, since I have the bluetooths connected using a different app, but still connected nonetheless. I scoured the interwebs for many differen tutorials, learning about the different parts I used in my code while also learning that there's a lot more to app development that I anticipated.

Anybody out there can help? I'd much appreciate some advice.

Ionic code attached.